# How to save data in Json format in React-admin v3?

Tags: json, user-input, react-admin

I created JsonInput, which sends a json object to the input SimpleForm, however, a modified version of it gets into the Data Provider.

that's what is sent to the input:

```
json: {
   "FunctionalGroup": [
      {
         "uaIDref": [
            "2104"
         ],
         "_Name": "Текущие параметры",
         "_ID": "33"
      },
      {
         "uaIDref": [
            "2100"
         ],
         "_Name": "Текущие параметры пониженной точности",
         "_ID": "34"
      },
   ],
   "_Name": "Прибор 1",
   "_ID": "32"
}
```

that's what came to the server:

```
json: {
    "FunctionalGroup": [
        {
          "uaIDref": [
            "2104"
          ],
          "_Name": "Текущие параметры",
          "_ID": "33"
        },
        {
          "uaIDref": [
            "2100"
          ],
          "_Name": "Текущие параметры пониженной точности",
          "_ID": "34"
        }
    ],
    "FunctionalGroupIds": "",
    "_Name": "Прибор 1",
    "_ID": "32"
},
```

after a response from the server with this object, this is what came in the field:

```
json: {
  FunctionalGroup: [
    {
      uaIDref: [
        '2104'
      ]
    },
    {
      uaIDref: [
        '2100'
      ]
    }
  ],
  FunctionalGroupIds: ''
}
```

what kind of magic is this?

I did some tests. When I converted the object to a string, the correct json was sent to the server, however, in the field after the server responded, the modified object was displayed again.
I found out that the conversion is related to redux.js, but what exactly happens is not understood.

Please give any comments on this.
How can I make save json?